# Understanding AudioBuffer to ArrayBuffer conversion

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, web-audio-api

I have an AudioBuffer client-side that I'd like to AJAX to a express server.

[This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) shows how a XMLHttpRequest can send/receive binary data - ArrayBuffer.

An ArrayBuffer is different to an AudioBuffer (or so I believe) as I decoded an ArrayBuffer to make the AudioBuffer in the first place. This was done using [decodeAudioData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/decodeAudioData) as part of the Web Audio API.

So my question is, can I convert an AudioBuffer back to an ArrayBuffer?

If this is possible, I'd like to then send the ArrayBuffer to my express server and then forward it on to a S3 bucket as shown in [this example](http://blog.katworksgames.com/2014/01/26/nodejs-deploying-files-to-aws-s3/).

In that example, the code PUTs a Buffer in a S3 bucket created via a fs.readFileSync(). I assume the difference between a Buffer and ArrayBuffer wont be an issue with S3 :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [copyFromChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer/copyFromChannel) method, then convert the `Float32Array` to an `ArrayBuffer`.

```
var myArrayBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(2, frameCount, audioCtx.sampleRate);  
var anotherArray = new Float32Array();
myArrayBuffer.copyFromChannel(anotherArray,1,0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One thing, am I right in thinking that in the example code the copyFromChannel would create an ArrayBuffer with only a mono out, and not a 2 channel stereo ArrayBuffer?

Comment: That's right. You'll have to retrieve the data from both channels and find out how to "merge" these.

Comment: I've just found something about `createChannelMerger`, hope this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createChannelMerger