# Text to audio give error using php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When i give $les small string like "hello how are you" it works fine but when string length is high like 500words then it gives error!
if i give

```
$les = 'Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, hello hihoe hihh';
```

then it works fine if i enter just one letter more then it gives error

Thanks for any solution
[image]

```
$les  = $lesson->full_text;

    /* for text to audio */
    
    $txt  =htmlspecialchars($les);
    $txt=rawurlencode($txt);
    
    $audio = file_get_contents('https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=gtx&q='.$txt.'&tl=es');
    $speech="<audio controls='controls'><source src='data:audio/mpeg;base64,".base64_encode($audio)."'></audio>";
    echo $speech; exit();
    

    /* end text to audio */
```

Comment: A URL should not exceed 2000 characters. I think when you are using 500 words, it exceeds the limit.

Comment: yes! can any solution to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of character length limitation.

Hope this trick helps:

```
public function index() {
    $max = 80;
    $les = 'test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test';

    if (strlen($les) < $max) {
        $txt[] = rawurlencode(htmlspecialchars($les));
    } else {
        $txt = chunk_split($les, $max);
        $txt = explode("\r\n", $txt);
    }

    foreach ($txt as $t) {
        if (strlen($t) == 0) { continue; }
        $t = rawurlencode(htmlspecialchars(trim($t)));
        $audio = file_get_contents('https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?client=gtx&q='.$t.'&tl=en-US');
        echo "<audio controls='controls'><source src='data:audio/mpeg;base64,".base64_encode($audio)."'></audio>";
    }
}
```

After this you could do your goal by joining audios or play each other in sequence.

Comment: thanks now i get 10audio. how can i join all  in one audio. any suggestion

Comment: there are multiple ways like: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65767933/8495783

Comment: i am facing one issue in stripe on live mode.. can you tell me the solution.. actually it works fine when on test mode but on live mode when on click button 3dsecure popup open after verification it close then it not further run .. even not go in method you can find this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71322782/stripe-on-test-mode-works-fine-but-on-live-mode-it-does-not-work-in-laravel